# Why does pressing 'b', 'n', '=', F4, or F8 activate Windows Key? Is keyboard damaged?

Tags: windows, keyboard, windows-11, on-screen-keyboard

I have come across a similar problem described in [this thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-key-stuck-down-not-physically/42a9ccd3-5362-4930-98e1-257c5b4ae668) where the Windows key <kbd>Win</kbd> has the effect as if it is toggled and constantly held down so typing is impossible. And I have discovered that pressing <kbd>b</kbd>, <kbd>n</kbd>, <kbd>=</kbd>, <kbd>F4</kbd>, or <kbd>F8</kbd> activate this behavior. When running `osk.exe` you can see that the key gets toggled and permanently activated in the On-Screen Keyboard if any of the aforementioned keys is pressed. So typing any letter will have the effect of <kbd>Windows Key</kbd>+<kbd>the letter</kbd> and trigger all sorts of unwanted shortcut behavior. Is the keyboard damaged or can this behavior be disabled? The workaround is to press the windows key again to toggle off it again.

Comment: Does it happen with an external keyboard?

Comment: i forgot to mention this. it works with external keyboard. so i guess the laptop keyboard is busted and needs replacement?